# Can you build a model that normalises FEATURES using the test set while avoiding data leakage?

Tags: supervised-learning

Just can't wrap my head around this one.

I understand that:

- Normalising a target variable using the test set uses information on that target variable in the test set. This means we get inflated performance metrics that cannot be replicated once we receive a *new* test set (which does not have a target variable available).

However, when we receive a new test set, we *do* have predictor variables available. What is wrong with using these to normalise? Yes, the predictors contain information that *relates* to the target variable, however that's literally the definition of predicting using a model, we use the information in predictors to get specific predictions for a target. Why can't it be built-in to the model definition that it uses input data to normalise, before predicting?

The performance metrics, surely, *wouldn't* be skewed as we are just using information from the predictors.

Yes, the test set is supposed to be 'unseen', but in reality, surely it's only the *test set target variable* that is unseen, not the predictors.

I have read around this and answers so far are vague, just repeating that test set is unseen and that we gain information about the test set. I would really appreciate an answer on why we can't use *specifically the predictors*, as I think the target case is obvious.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having gone away and thought about my Q - normalising our data on the training set as well - I realise this doesn't make much sense. Normalising is not part of the training, but something we do *before* training, therefore normalising w/ test set features is fine as an idea, but we then would have to go train this normalised data on the training set outcomes. I originally thought "normalise on more data" > "normalise on less data" but actually we'd normalise on one set (training + test), then fit on another (training). Probably get a more poorly trained model as a result and so as I believe it's a stupid idea!